# Help with MOSFETs to switch sensor on and off

Tags: arduino, mosfet, esp32

I have a question, I have noticed similar solution for voltage divider to measure voltage on battery with ESP32 using one pin to enable the divider and have it otherwise off the voltage to save power. My question is if the same principle can be used for sensors, let's say the ESP32 wakes up and depending on time it wants to read a specific sensor, so no need to power all of them all the time. Would this work l? Or is there some glaring issue with this schematic? We are talking about 3.3 V logic and power to the sensors.

[image]

Comment: One thing to be aware of: If this sensor is on the same I/O bus as other sensors and you're trying to only power one sensor at a time, you might run into issues. If unpowered, devices can sometimes be "partially" powered via their I/O pins, causing erratic behavior on the bus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Other than Q5 being upside down, it looks great.
Pay attention to the parallel "body diode" between drain and source in a MOSFET.

It may take some time for the sensor to stabilize, check the datasheet or experiment.
A tiny portion of this delay will come from R5 and the capacitance of Q3.  (Do not remove R5, it reduces ringing and current spikes.)
\$ t = 2 \cdot R \cdot C \$
Ought to be enough time for the MOSFET, but the sensor may also need some time to stabilize.

Comment: Ah, regarding the Q5 so as it is now it would allow passage of the VBAT+PROT to Sensor VC+ right away, right ? I need to switch it around, as you say.

Comment: Yes, exactly...

Comment: Thanks so much @Oskar Skog

Answer (score 3):

There is no glaring issue in your scheme. It should work. When the sensor is OFF, the output of the sensor will be floating. So, you'll need to manage that as well. For eg., if the output is going as an input to ESP32, you should have a pullup or pulldown enabled to define the IO.

EDIT: If EN_SENSOR could float when VBAT+PROT is present, better to add say 100k resistor from EN_SENSOR to ground.

You have to flip Q5 as mentioned in the other answer. Missed that one.

Comment: Except Q5..........

Comment: You are right, adding the pull down 100k on en_sensor should be added to have it clearly defined. Thanks, I know these are probably super basic questions, but I'm trying to learn it in my 40ties :D and I'm surprised how nice people are, kind of expected more harsh answers :)

Comment: Its the EE section (not itchy downvote trigger finger python re!). IRL88721PBF is quite a nice N channel mosfet you can operate from 3V3 logic btw